# Using the CSS function in jQuery to Set the "left" margin of several divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a menu type bar at the top of the page. I want each mini section of the menu (an individual div) to be a link to a different part of my page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var w = window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;

    var h = window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;
 
 
 
 $("#divone").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#divone").css("left", 0px);
 $("#divtwo").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#divtwo").css("left", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#divthree").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#divthree").css("left", ((2 * parseInt(w)) / 6)px);
 $("#divfour").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#divfour").css("left", ((3 * parseInt(w)) / 6)px);
 $("#news").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#news").css("left", ((4 * parseInt(w)) / 6)px);
 $("#sen").css("width", (parseInt(w) / 6)px);
 $("#sen").css("left", ((5 * parseInt(w)) / 6)px);
 
 
});
```

I want to make each individual div to be a certain distance apart from the left edge of the browser window, so that the menu gets spread out evenly. Basically, imagine a bunch of tabs open, and you being able to click on a tab to switch pages. I want to do something like that.

But when I run the code, all the divs overlap each other. The intention of the design is to have some divs further to the right than others, but it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

All of those divs are contained within a parent div. The parent div's position is set to relative, and the children to absolute.

I tried setting display to inline-block as well. Did not work.

Comment: This code doesn't compile; you're missing the quotes around `'px'` and you need to use the concatenation (`+`) operator to prepend your `parseInt` calculations to that unit.

Comment: Should I put quotes only around the letters px or around the numbers and the px? Edit: Also, can you give an example of how to concatenate the parseInt?

Comment: Let me just start an answer for you :)

Comment: Never mind, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Without your HTML or CSS code available, I was able to make your syntax more correct but not able to check whether or not this does what you intended.)

Notes:

- Checking `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` is sufficient; no need to fall back to any of those other properties.
- `jQuery#css` takes a map of key-value pairs, so you don't have to use multiple function calls to set more than one CSS property
- `variable | 0` is a common pattern to convert any value into an integer, and it can replace the use of `parseInt`.
- You have to put quotation marks (either single or double) around strings, like `'Hello'` or `'px'`, before you can attach numbers to them with `+`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var w = window.innerWidth | 0
    var h = window.innerHeight | 0
 
    $("#divone")  .css({ width: (w/6 + 'px'), left: '0px' })
    $("#divtwo")  .css({ width: (w/6 + 'px'), left: (  w/6 + 'px') })
    $("#divthree").css({ width: (w/6 + 'px'), left: (2*w/6 + 'px') })
    $("#divfour") .css({ width: (w/6 + 'px'), left: (4*w/6 + 'px') })
    $("#news")    .css({ width: (w/6) + 'px', left: (4*w/6) + 'px' })
    $("#sen")     .css({ width: (w/6) + 'px', left: (5*w/6) + 'px' })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```